# How to use INITIAL_STATE injection token with dependencies?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ngrx

I have a lazy-loaded module with a ngrx/store for feature `StoreModule.forFeature('tasks', tasksReducer)`. I need to set the initial state for it, but the values that I need to set require a dependency injection to get them (those values are selected from another feature store in a service). I read that it's possible to use INITIAL_STATE injection token for this purpose. I tried the following:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '@realiecho/shared/shared.module';
import { tasksRoutes } from './tasks.routing';
import { TasksComponent } from './tasks/tasks.component';
import { INITIAL_STATE, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { tasksReducer } from '@realiecho/main/tasks/store/tasks.reducer';
import { TasksEffects } from '@realiecho/main/tasks/store/tasks.effects';
import { TasksTableViewComponent } from '@realiecho/main/tasks/tasks/tasks-table-view/tasks-table-view.component';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';

import { InitialStateService } from '@reali/web-core';

export const TASK_EFFECTS = [
    TasksEffects
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        tasksRoutes,
        SharedModule,
        EffectsModule.forFeature(TASK_EFFECTS),
        StoreModule.forFeature('tasks', tasksReducer),
    ],
    declarations: [
        TasksComponent,
        TasksTableViewComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: INITIAL_STATE,
            useFactory: getInitialState,
            deps: [InitialStateService]
        }
    ]
})
export class TasksModule {
}


export function getInitialState(initService: InitialStateService) {

     return initService.getInitState();

}
```

but when I run it, the initial state is `undefined` regardless of what I return in `initService.getInitState()`, even if I return hardcoded constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { inject } from '@angular/core';  

    export function getInitialState() {
     return inject(InitService).getInitState();
    }
```

can you try something like that?
or

```
export class TasksModule {
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TasksModule ,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: INITIAL_STATE,
            useFactory: getInitialState,
            deps: [InitialStateService]
        }
    ]
    }
  }
```

then for appModule

```
@NgModule({
        imports: [
            ...
           TaskModule.forRoot(),
          ...
        ],

    })
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help. The problem is that getInitialState() is not executed at all. Should I pass INITIAL_STATE token somewhere else except  `providers`?

Comment: this task module loaded lazy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to the following:
StoreModule.forFeature('tasks', tasksReducer, INITIAL_STATE)

Though I'm now struggling with how to reset the initial state in the reducer.

Cheers

James

Comment: This didn't help. I still see that the function `getInitState()` is executed, but the result is not assigned the initial state

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and unfortunately it isn't possible to use the `INITIAL_STATE` token for a feature module. I got the following answer via github:

> The `INITIAL_STATE` token is only used to set the initial state of the root module.
>   You could use the OnInitEffect lifecycle or the @ngrx/store/update-reducers action to dispatch a "set action" to set the state of the feature module in a reducer.

[Github Link](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2534)